# Windows version shows true value in design, but shows different value when I run program

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

I am developing a `WPF` `MVVM` application to show some `Windows System Informations` and practice some `MVVM`.

Somehow in design `Environment.OSVersion.ToString()` works correctly but after debug it does not. I tried debug and release modes but nothing is changed.

"Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.15063.0" was shown in design time:
[image]

"Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0" was shown in when I run the software:
[image]

My UserControl

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:WindowsVersionViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Text="{Binding Path=Version, Mode=OneWay}" />
</Grid>
```

My ViewModel

```
public class WindowsVersionViewModel : ObservableObject {
    public string Version { get; } = Environment.OSVersion.ToString();
}
```

How can I get correct version after run and why this happens?

Comment: This call isn't recommended from the documentation. "Starting with Windows 8, the OSVersion property returns the same major and minor version numbers for all Windows platforms. Therefore, we do not recommend that you retrieve the value of this property to determine the operating system version. "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because your application is not manifested for Windows 8.1 or later.

When a non-manifested application makes a call to [`GetVersionEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx), that function will return the version number of Windows 8.0 if it is run on later versions of the OS.

To fix this you need to manifest your application for the versions of Windows that you want to support.

To do so, you need to [add something to you application's `app.manifest` in the "compatibility" section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx).

For example:

```
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- A list of the Windows versions that this application has been tested on and is
           is designed to work with. Uncomment the appropriate elements and Windows will 
           automatically selected the most compatible environment. -->

      <!-- Windows Vista -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}" />-->

      <!-- Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}" />

      <!-- Windows 8 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}" />

      <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}" />

      <!-- Windows 10 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />
    </application>
</compatibility>
```

The reason this works in the designer is because Visual Studio is manifested for Windows 10, and the call to get the version number is being made in the context of Visual Studio.

Comment: This solved my problem thanks, but still this does not feel right to me :D

Comment: Rest assured, it is absolutely right, @tetralobita. Visual Studio is manifested correctly, so the actual OS version is reported at design time. Your app is not correctly manifested, so the OS lies to you about what its actual version is at run time.

Comment: By the way, it might be useful to mention that this behavior was chosen for backwards-compatibility considerations, and that it is not a problem in a well-designed application. You aren't supposed to be doing version-number checks; you should be checking support for specific features, instead.